# where column in from another select results with limit (mysql/mariadb)

Tags: sql, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

when i run this query returns all rows that their id exist in select from table2

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id in (
    SELECT id FROM table2 where name ='aaa'
)
```

but when i add limit or between  to second select :

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id in (
    SELECT id FROM table2 where name ='aaa' limit 4
)
```

returns this error :

> This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: why not put the limit in the outer select?

Comment: This is because *This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME
subquery'* What version are you using ?

Comment: Read [this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/subquery-limitations/#limit)

Comment: im using mariadb 10.3

Comment: i cant put limit in other select because other select in my project is a left join query and there are many duplicate ids , for example when i limit 10 it returns 8 or 1 or 3 or 9 rows from left table and 10 rows from right table

Comment: do you need to return only one row from table2 ?

Comment: no i need to return some ids from table2 with limit or between  2 numbers to put theme in last select  --->  "where in ('some ids from table2')"

Comment: when i use this works fine
 `SELECT * FROM job_forum WHERE id in (
SELECT id FROM job_forum  WHERE id>0 and id<10
)`
but according to [https://mariadb.com/kb/en/subquery-limitations/#limit] this type of limit not supported 
what is the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY`.  This is generally not recommended because that returns an arbitrary set of rows -- and those can change from one execution to another.

You can convert this to a `JOIN` -- fortunately.  If `id` is not duplicated in `table2`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1 JOIN
     (SELECT t2.id
      FROM table2 t2
      WHERE t2.name = 'aaa' 
      LIMIT 4
     ) t2
     USING (id);
```

If `id` can be duplicated in `table2`, then:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1 JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT t2.id
      FROM table2 t2
      WHERE t2.name = 'aaa' 
      LIMIT 4
     ) t2
     USING (id);
```

Another fun way uses `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
WHERE id <= ANY (SELECT t2.id
                 FROM table2 
                 WHERE t2.name = 'aaa'
                 ORDER BY t2.id
                 LIMIT 1 OFFSET 3
                );
```

`LIMIT` *is* allowed in a scalar subquery.

Comment: tanks 
`SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1 JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT t2.id
      FROM table2 t2
      WHERE t2.name = 'aaa' 
      LIMIT 4
     ) t2
     USING (id); `  worked

Answer (score 0):

You can use an analytic function such as `ROW_NUMBER()` in order to return one row from the subquery. I suppose, this way no problem would occur like raising too many rows issue :

```
SELECT * FROM
(
 SELECT t1.*,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t2.id DESC) AS rn
  FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
 WHERE t2.name ='aaa'
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

*P.S.: Btw, id columns are expected to be primary keys of your tables, aren't they ?*

**Update** ( depending on your need in the comment ) Consider using :

```
SELECT * FROM
(
 SELECT j.*,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY j.id DESC) AS rn2
  FROM job_forum j
  CROSS JOIN 
      ( SELECT t.*,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.id ORDER BY t2.id DESC) AS rn1 
          FROM table2 t2
         WHERE t2.name ='aaa'
           AND t2.id = j.id ) t2 
  WHERE rn1 = 1
) jj
WHERE rn2 <= 10
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id in (
SELECT id FROM table2  WHERE id>(SELECT MAX(id) FROM table2 )-11 and id<(SELECT MAX(id) FROM table2 )-0
)` 
this is what i need but it uses two more selects

Comment: tanks your answer is true but  that day i was very angry and tired ,  today i tested it